# What would happen if I call getpeername() and getsockname() on server socket at different positions?

Tags: c, sockets

In C with socket program, I am trying to insert the getpeername() and getsockname in **server** socket to print IP address of server socket and client socket on the server side. Note: my server socket uses INADDR_ANY. I put getpeername() and getsockname() in different positions:

1/ before bind(): The IP address of both client and server socket is 0.0.0.0

2/ after bind(): Again, the IP address of both client and server socket is 0.0.0.0

3/ after accept(): The IP address of client is 10.0.2.15 while the server socket is still 0.0.0.0

Are they correct? Can you explain why I got 0.0.0.0 instead of the specific address in these cases?

Note: In my opinion, I should get a specific IP address of server socket after bind() because bind() already bind the server socket to specific IP address. And for after accept(), I think both client socket and server socket should be specific IP address too instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: You need to call `getsockname()` and `getpeername()` on the socket descriptor that is returned by `accept()`, not on the socket descriptor of the listening server itself.  And no, binding the server to `0.0.0.0` does NOT bind the server to a specific IP, it binds the server to *all* local IPs, that is the whole point of `0.0.0.0`.  But `accept()` will bind the accepted client to the specific local IP that accepted it.

Comment: Related: [Can not print out specific address of server socket with getsockname()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52807653/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce your problem; e.g. consider

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in  addr = {
        .sin_family = AF_INET,
        .sin_port   = 0,
        .sin_addr   = { INADDR_ANY },
    };

    int         fd;
    int         c_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in  p_addr;
    socklen_t       a_len = sizeof p_addr;

    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(fd, (void const *)&addr, sizeof addr);

    getpeername(fd, (void *)&p_addr, &a_len);
    getsockname(fd, (void *)&p_addr, &a_len);

    listen(fd, 10);
    c_fd = accept(fd, NULL, NULL);

    getpeername(c_fd, (void *)&p_addr, &a_len);
    getsockname(c_fd, (void *)&p_addr, &a_len);
}
```

Running it through `strace` and connecting to the bind-address, shows

```
$ strace ./a.out
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
getpeername(3, 0x7ffdcf3af130, [16])    = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(60093), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, [16]) = 0
listen(3, 10)                           = 0
accept(3, NULL, NULL)                   = 4
getpeername(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(35048), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(60093), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 0
```

In your cases 1 + 2, there is no server and `getpeername()` will fail with `ENOTCONN`.

Before `accept()` the `getsockname` returns `0.0.0.0` because you are listening on `INADDR_ANY`.

But after `accept()` the `getsockname()` **will** return the local address.