# Can not print out specific address of server socket with getsockname()

Tags: c, sockets

I use getpeername() and getsockname() to print out the IP address of client socket and server socket on server side. However, just only IP address of client socket is specified, while the IP address of server socket is 0.0.0.0. How would I can fix that problem so that the IP address of server socket can be specified?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h>
 #include "Practical.h"

 static const int MAXPENDING = 5; // Maximum outstanding connection requests

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if (argc != 2) // Test for correct number of arguments
    DieWithUserMessage("Parameter(s)", "<Server Port>");

  in_port_t servPort = atoi(argv[1]); // First arg: local port

 // Create socket for incoming connections
  int servSock; // Socket descriptor for server
 if ((servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("socket() failed");

 // Construct local address structure
 struct sockaddr_in servAddr; // Local address
 memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr)); // Zero out structure
 servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4 address family
 servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // Any incoming interface
 servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort); // Local port

 // Bind to the local address
 if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("bind() failed");

 // Mark the socket so it will listen for incoming connections
 if (listen(servSock, MAXPENDING) < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("listen() failed");

 for (;;) { // Run forever
    struct sockaddr_in clntAddr; // Client address
    // Set length of client address structure (in-out parameter)
    socklen_t clntAddrLen = sizeof(clntAddr);
    // Wait for a client to connect
    int clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
    if (clntSock < 0)
       DieWithSystemMessage("accept() failed"); 

   // clntSock is connected to a client!

   char clntName[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]; // String to contain client address
   if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clntAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, clntName, sizeof(clntName)) != NULL)
       printf("Handling client %s/%d\n", clntName, ntohs(clntAddr.sin_port));
   else
       puts("Unable to get client address");
   getpeername(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
   inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clntAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, clntName, sizeof(clntName));
   printf("After accept(): The client IP address is: %s and client port is: %u \n", clntName, ntohs(clntAddr.sin_port));

   char serverIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
   socklen_t servlen = sizeof(servAddr);
   inet_ntop(AF_INET, &servAddr.sin_addr, serverIP, sizeof(serverIP));
   getsockname(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, &servlen);
   printf("After accept(): The server IP address is %s and server port is %u \n", serverIP, servPort);

   HandleTCPClient(clntSock);
 }
 // NOT REACHED
}
```

The output is:

IP address of client socket: 10.0.2.15

IP address of server socket: 0.0.0.0

So, how I can make the IP address of server socket be specific like 10.0.2.15 instead of 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     int clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
>
>    getpeername(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);
> ```

You have to call `getpeername()` with `clntSock`. Ditto for `getsockname()`.

Both functions can fail (which happens probably in your program) when called with an invalid socket and return random data.

Comment: The getpeername() which print out client IP address still works correct. But my trouble is at getsockname() which printout server IP address because it can not print specific IP address as I expect

Comment: the `getsockname()` call uses the wrong socket (`servSock`) too.

Comment: Also, there is no need to call `getpeername()` in the code shown, since it will return the same `sockaddr_in` data that `accept()` has already given you for the remote peer.